# Start the function again on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a quiz which takes answer from user, checks it and shows whether the answer is correct or incorrect. There are 8 questions in it. I want to start the quiz again once all these 8 questions are completed.  How do I do it ?

This is my code

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="qscore">
  <span id="scr"></span>
</div>
<center>
  <div class="qstart">start</div>
</center>

<div class="qarea">
  <div class="question">father</div>
  <div class="canswer">Vater</div>
  <textarea class="abox" placeholder="Translate the text to German"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="qarea">
  <div class="question">My father is baba</div>
  <div class="canswer">Mein Vater ist baba</div>
  <textarea class="abox"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="qarea">
  <div class="question">Land</div>
  <div class="canswer">Land</div>
  <textarea class="abox"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="qarea">
  <div class="question">My Mother</div>
  <div class="canswer">Meine Mutter</div>
  <textarea class="abox"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="qarea">
  <div class="question">Brother</div>
  <div class="canswer">Bruder</div>
  <textarea class="abox" placeholder="Translate the text to German"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="qarea">
  <div class="question">City</div>
  <div class="canswer">Stadt</div>
  <textarea class="abox"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="qarea">
  <div class="question">Woman</div>
  <div class="canswer">Frau</div>
  <textarea class="abox"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="qarea">
  <div class="question">Man</div>
  <div class="canswer">Mann</div>
  <textarea class="abox"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="qsubmit">submit</div>
<div class="qcontinue">continue</div>
<div class="correct">Correct</div>
<div class="incorrect">Incorrect</div>
<div class="qrating"></div>
<div class="startagain">startagain</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//declare variables

var qarea = $(".qarea");
var totalqarea = qarea.length;
var startagain = $(".startagain");
var canswer = $(".canswer")
var qsubmit = $(".qsubmit");
var qcontinue = $(".qcontinue");
var qscore = $(".qscore");
var counter = 0;

//hide unrequired 
qcontinue.hide();
qsubmit.hide();
startagain.hide();
$("startagain")
$(".correct,.incorrect").hide();
qsubmit.hide();
$(".qscore,.qrating").hide();

$(".canswer").hide();
qarea.hide();

var qstart = $(".qstart");

//intiate click on start

qstart.click(function () {
    $(".correct,.incorrect").hide();
    var counter = 0;
    $(".abox").val('');
    qsubmit.show();
    $(".qrating").hide();
    qarea.eq(counter).show();
    qstart.hide();
    var i = 0;
    $(".qscore").text("Score:" + i + "/" + totalqarea).show();
    //loop();    function loop() 

    //initate submit

    qsubmit.bind("click", function () {
        qstart.hide();


        var ma = canswer.eq(counter).text();

        var mal = ma.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "").replace("ü", "u").replace("ä", "ä").replace("ö", "o").replace("ß", "ss").replace("Ä", "A").replace("Ö", "O").replace("Ü", "U").toLowerCase();
        var masplt = mal.split(" ");
        var ua = $("textarea").eq(counter).val();

        var ual = ua.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "").replace("ü", "u").replace("ä", "a").replace("ö", "o").replace("ß", "ss").replace("Ä", "A").replace("Ö", "O").replace("Ü", "U").toLowerCase();
        var uasplt = ual.split(" ");
        var n = mal.localeCompare(ual);
        counter = counter + 1;
        qarea.eq(counter - 1).hide();
        // checks correct answer and gives score
        if (n == 0) {


            var praise = ["Well Done !!..You got it right !! ", "Nice....You got it right!! ", "Perfect....You got it right!! "]
            var r = Math.round(Math.random());

            $(".correct").text(praise[r] + " : The answer is " + ma).show();
            i = i + 1;
            $(".qscore").text("Score:" + i + "/" + totalqarea).show();



            //gives incorrect     
        } else {
            qarea.hide();
            $(".incorrect").text("Oops....the correct answer is....");
            for (var j = 0; j < masplt.length; j++) {
                if (masplt[j] !== uasplt[j]) {


                    $(".incorrect").append(" <span style='font-size:32px'>" + masplt[j] + "</span>").show();

                } else {
                    $(".incorrect").append(" " + masplt[j]).show();
                }
            }
            //$(".incorrect").text("Oops....the correct answer is " + ma).show();

        }

        qsubmit.hide();
        qcontinue.show();
        qcontinue.click(function () {
            qarea.eq(counter).show();
            $(".correct,.incorrect").hide();
            qsubmit.show();
            qcontinue.hide();
        })

        if (totalqarea == counter) {
           qcontinue.show();
            qcontinue.click(function () {
                qsubmit.hide();

                qstart.text("start again").show();
                if (i < (totalqarea - 6) && i < (totalqarea - 4)) {
                    $(".qrating").text("Your scored  " + i + "/" + totalqarea + ". ...You need some more practice. Try it again.").show();
                } else if (i > (totalqarea - 4) && i < (totalqarea - 2)) {
                    $(".qrating").text("Your scored  " + i + "/" + totalqarea + "....Not bad !!").show();
                } else {
                    $(".qrating").html("Your scored  " + i + "/" + totalqarea + "....Wünderbar !! Keep it up !!").show();
                }
                $("#scr").text('');
            })
            qstart.click(function () {

            })
        }

    })
})
})
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qFa39/11/

Thanks.

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been removed from the Web. Please do the same in your HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Wow this javascript needs some tidying urg! :)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Did you see the fiddle ? I want to repeat the quiz again once it is completed but not able to do it .

Comment: Try to set your counter back to 0

Comment: not working by setting couter to 0

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're declaring 2 different counter variables. The one declared under the "declare variables" comment and the one declared within `qstart.click()`. To fix your problem replace the line inside `qstart.click()` (line 31 in the jsfiddle) with:

```
counter = 0;
```

No `var` preceeding it. This way javascript will understand you are refering to the first counter and not creating a new var called counter. Have a read up on [scope in javascript](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) for more info.

Although this does reveal another bug with our code where the 'Start Again' button does then not hide properly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Setting counter to 0 repeats the quiz but doesn't starts from the beginning. Any other way to do it using recursive function ?

Comment: To hide the qrating and qstart you could simply replace line 93 in the jsfiddle with: `$(".correct,.incorrect,.qstart,.qrating").hide();`

How do you mean a recursive function?

Also, if the answer is right, would you mind accepting it with the tick? Cheers.

Comment: It almost worked but if you see, all questions are not getting repeated. Something is getting wrong with the counter ...